# Is lock need with this.Invoke

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I came across a third-party piece of code which is using invoke to update a control, but the invoke is inside a lock statement eg

```
 lock (mi) 
 {
   this.Invoke(mi);
 }
```

where mi is System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker mi.

The method that is called is just updating one windows control (a listbox) and is initialised when the usercontrol is created and never changed.

So two questions

1. Is there any need for the lock?
2. Is it likely to cause problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a lock around `Control.Invoke` is asking for trouble. You're basically saying, "I'll wait until the other thread has handled my delegate" - but if *that* thread (the UI thread) tries to acquire the same lock, it won't be able to because the worker thread already has it. Bang - instant deadlock.

With `BeginInvoke` it wouldn't be a problem, but it still wouldn't be a good idea. Basically this looks like the code of someone whose idea of making code thread-safe is to slap locks left, right and centre.

Now as the code is locking on the delegate reference, it's hard to say whether anything else *will* try to acquire the same lock... but if it doesn't, the lock is pretty pointless to start with.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that would be answer, otherwise I would have to revisit all the invokes I have ever written.